# Shell output of `ls | cat > new_file `

Tags: shell, pipe, io-redirection, concurrency

The behavior of dash (and also bash) looks non-intuitive in this case.

It seems that `new_file` is created before `ls` is executed.
Is it specified in POSIX?

Comment: If it's non-intuitive, it's because your intuition on pipes is wrong. `ls` is not executed before `cat >newfile`: the two are executed at the same time. Whether `new_file` is created before or after `ls` reaches the point where it would list it is a race. It's a race that `>new_file` will usually win, because creating a file takes less long than reading an executable and starting to execute it. But if you run it a large number of times, I expect you'll sometimes see `ls` win.